# mongoid configuration on ruby without framework

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, minitest

I try to write business logic of my application. It is all ruby classes. There is no database or no UI framework like Rails, Sinatra. I only have a Gem_file on business logic and, Gem_file only contain "mini_test" gem. I use  mini_test for testing business logic. Now, I need to add  a database to the system. How can I do this? 
mongoid configuration is made in application.file on Rails. But ,I don't use Rails or any other framework. Is there anyway to make configuration of mongoid without framework like Rails, Sinatra.
I hope I can explain my problem. Also, I add my codes in below:

**this is my context-**

```
class HeadTeacherDefineAcademicYearContext
  attr_reader :person, :academicyear

  def initialize(person, academicyear)
    @person, @academicyear = person, academicyear
    @person.extend HeadTeacher
  end

  def call
   @person.define_academic_year @academicyear
  end
end
```

**this is my role module**

```
module HeadTeacher
  def define_academic_year(academicyear)
     #i write db save process here using any database
  end
end
```

**my model class**

```
class AcademicYear
  attr_accessor :year
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include `gem 'mongoid'` in your Gemfile and install it. After that, you can require and initialize Mongoid where you need it:

```
require 'mongoid'
Mongoid.load!("mongoid.yml", :development)
```

It expects a `mongoid.yml` file with configuration. Examlpe:

```
development:
   sessions:
     default:
      database: myapp_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
```

Of course, you can use another context than `:development`, maybe assign it via a environment variable. Now, add `Mongoid::Document` to your model:

```
class AcademicYear
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :year, type: Integer
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `gem "mongoid", "~> 3.0.0"` to your Gemfile
Then put configuration yaml file to your project with contents like this:

```
development:
  sessions: 
    default:
      database: mongoid
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
```

Then use `Mongoid.load!("path/to/your/mongoid.yml", :development)` in your app.

In every class you want to save objects to DB you have to `include Mongoid::Document`.

So your example becomes:

```
class HeadTeacherDefineAcademicYearContext
  attr_reader :person, :academicyear
  field :person, type: String
  field :academicyear, type: Date
  ...
end
```

You should better [check mongoid docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html) for stuff to do next.

Comment: I want to ask one thing about mongoid.yml. Where do I add mongoid.load command? I have no framework, no file about application start. I have only Gemfile and pure Ruby classes.